# LibreOffice Calc datetime shortcut insert

Tags: datetime, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, ubuntu-16.04

In LibreOffice when I format a cell as ***Time*** with format ***MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS***, I use the shortcut **ctrl+;** it enters the date like **08/04/2016 16:35:05** - which is OK. But when I do it the second time on the same cell with the value of the previous **ctrl+;** it only enters time without date and in another format, like **04:25:18 PM**.

This weirdness appeared after LibreOffice version changed, after I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.

```
Version: 5.1.4.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1
```

What can I do to not need to clear the value for ctrl+; to work?

Comment: When I tried it, `ctrl+;` produced `08/04/2016 00:00:00` the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon) inserts the date.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> (colon) inserts the time.
- Use both to insert date and time in the same cell: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>

This is like the behavior of Excel described at: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138: